# Flutter Container BoxShadow doesn't show

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Here it's my code in this moment:

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
        end: FractionalOffset.topRight,
        colors: <Color>[Colors.purple, AppBaseColors.orange],
      ),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.yellow)]
    ),
    child: Material(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("tapped");
        },
        child: Container(
          width: ButtonTheme.of(context).minWidth,
          height: ButtonTheme.of(context).height,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "log in",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      color: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  ),
),
```

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED:**

- Add the **boxShadow** in the first **Container**
- Add the **boxShadow** in the second **Container**
- Add another **Container** with **boxShadow** as a parent of **ClipRRect**
- Add the **boxShadow** in **Material** as shadowColor (ofc is not working because I don't have any kind of shadow)
- Adding also the **spreadRadius** and **blurRadius** in all of the cases from above, but nothing changed.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I think the material widget is hiding the box shadow effect i would suggest to remove the container and add elevation to Material or remove the Material widget

Comment: I can not do that, or at least I don't know how... If I will delete the Material widget I'm not going to have the click effect if you will tap on that button. Also if I'm going to remove the first container and add the BoxDecoration on the second Container I will also say goodbye to the click effect because. So it's not quite a solution for me at least with the knowledge I have for the moment.

Comment: the click effect is assured by the inkewell widget so i think you dont need to worry

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to do these changes:

- remove the `ClipRRect` widget.
- add `borderRadius` inside `BoxDecoration`.
- add an `Offset` to your `BoxShadow`.

  ```
  Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  end: FractionalOffset.topRight,
                  colors: <Color>[Colors.purple, Colors.orange],
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(color: Colors.yellow, offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0))
                ]),
            child: Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print("tapped");
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: ButtonTheme.of(context).minWidth,
                  height: ButtonTheme.of(context).height,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "log in",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ),
  ```

Comment: Actually, it's almost correct, with this solution you have the problem that if you will click on the button the click effect is not going to have rounded corners. Could you also fix this last detail?

Comment: done , added borderRadius and clipBehavior inside Material widget. Don't forget use hot-restart

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by removing the `clipBehavior` or setting it to `Clip.none`.